# Reading data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to read data from a [website](http://www.tip.it/runescape/gec/price_graph.php?avg=1&start=1327715574&mainitem=10350&item=10350) that contains only text. I'd like to read only the data that follows "&values". I've been able to open the entire website, but I don't know how to get rid of the extraneous data and I don't know any HTML. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of that url look like url parameters. You could use `urllib.parse_qs` to parse them into a dict:

```
import urllib2
import urlparse

url = 'http://www.tip.it/runescape/gec/price_graph.php?avg=1&start=1327715574&mainitem=10350&item=10350'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
params = urlparse.parse_qs(content)
print(params['values'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the `re` module (although if you do eventually move to HTML, [regex is not the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). Here is a basic example that grabs the text after `&values` and returns the following number/comma/space combinations:

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://www.tip.it/runescape/gec/price_graph.php?avg=1&start=1327715574&mainitem=10350&item=10350'
>>> contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> values = re.findall(r'&values=([\d,\s]*)', contents)
>>> values[0].split(',')
['33900000', '33900000', '33900000', #continues....]
```

Comment: user1709173 Happy it helps! However @unutbu's answer is pretty clever :)